# Question about converting 220V lamp to 110V

Tags: electrical-engineering

I have an old classic lamp (Tolomeo).
It was purchased when we lived in Singapore, so it is designed for 220V.
Since we moved to US, I have not been able to use it as the power supply here is 110V.

The adapter of the lam says:
Power Supply Type BL2UK
240V~ 50Hz TW 10ºC
For PL Lamps Type:
(then is lists some options)

Now I was wondering if someone can help me with these questions.
1. Will replacing this adapter solve my problem?
2. Will I also need to change the bulb? The current bulb it uses is: 10W
3. If adapter needs to be replaced, which one should I replace it with?

Thanks a lot for any help or guidance.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a halogen lamp, get a new power supply that will produce the correct output in terms of power, voltage and current - you don’t mention those but they should be there stated on the original.

Then you can get the correct bulb and use it.

Or rewire it and change the bulb fitting for a bulb type that is convenient and locates the filament in the same position relative to the reflector.

Comment: Hi, its a fluorescent bulb. The data on the adapter says this: 240V~ 50Hz TW 10ºC and 1x 13W 0.166A PF 0.45 (is that what you were saying when you referred to Voltage, Power, and Current?

Answer (score 0):

Search for "120 to 240 transformer adaptor usa to uk step up"

You'll need to choose one with a power rating higher than your lamp.

Something suitable is about £10

You shouldn't need to even change the plug.

[image]